# How do you save the data of an int, and then edit the number onclick of a button?

Tags: android, int, sharedpreferences, save

I am trying to have it so when you click one of the answeers (Q1A1 or Q1A2) it will add a number of points to the testScore int so I can then later call that in a later class so the score they got would be posted there. Thanks to anyone who helps in advance!
here's my code,

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Test extends Activity implements OnClickListener 

{

    TextView Q1A1;
    TextView Q1A2;
    TextView test;

    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";
    public static final int testScore = 0;

    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.test);
        Q1A1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Q1A1);
        Q1A2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Q1A2);
        Q1A1.setOnClickListener(this);
        Q1A2.setOnClickListener(this);
        test = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.test);




        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
        test.setText(settings.getString("YourScore", "No Score"));


    }

    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        switch(v.getId())
        {
        case R.id.Q1A1:

            SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
            editor.putInt("YourScore", (testScore + 10));
            editor.commit();

            //Intent FinalScore = new Intent(this, FinalScore.class);
            //startActivity(FinalScore);
            break;
        case R.id.Q1A2:

            break;
        }   
    }   
}
```

thanks for the help

Comment: Where, specifically, are you having an issue? This code seems okay on first look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are are saving your score as an int but calling it as a string.

Change

test.setText(settings.getString("YourScore" , "No Score"));

To

test.setText(""+settings.getInt("YourScore" , 0));

Comment: Second thing is testScore always starts at zero. You may want to set it to your saved score. testScore = settings.getInt("YourScore" , 0 );

Comment: thanks it work but now what if I want to have a second button that adds a different number to the score but still in the save, if that made sense.

so if I have a second button Q1A2 whith all the same code but + 5 instead of 10 I get an error on the second "settings" and "editor" saying to change the name but them wont  the set text not work?

Comment: To be honest I am not sure what you are asking this time.  If you could  mark this answer as solved that would be great.  If you can't resolve your new problem try posting it in a new question with your updated code.  If I see it I will try to solve it for you.